# Use selected Option as variable in PHP Select Dropdown

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm pulling data from an Azure SQL database using PHP and have successfully created a drop-down (Select) box with Options that are pulled from the database.
The SQL query returns 2 columns, Title & Cycle_ID.

I have set the Title as the text string and the Cycle_ID as the value.
I now want to store the value (Cycle_ID) of the current selection in a variable (MyVariable), which I will use in the SQL query for the next drop-down box I'm creating, i.e. WHERE Cycle_ID = MyVariable. 
This way the user progressively narrows their selection as they work their way down through my drop-down boxes.
My current code is below, but I don't know how to create and store the current selection to MyVariable.

```
<?php
//create the database connection and define the query
$serverName = "myserver";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "mydatabase",
    "Uid" => "mysqlaccount",
    "PWD" => "mypassword"
);
//Establishes the connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

//defines cycle query
$cyclesql= "SELECT [Cycle_ID]
      ,[Title]
  FROM [ods].[Cycle]
  WHERE End_Date > DATEADD(month,-6,GETDATE()) AND Updated IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY Cycle_ID Asc";
$cycleResults= sqlsrv_query($conn, $cyclesql);

if ($cycleResults == FALSE)
    echo (sqlsrv_errors());
?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="cyclefile.php" method="post"> 
<div id="select">
<p>Select the week:</p><select name='Week'>
<option value="">Select...</option>
<?php
//starts loop
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($cycleResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) {
//defines cycle variable
$cycle = $row['Title'];
//defines cycle_id variable
$cycle_id = $row['Cycle_ID'];
//displays cycle variable as option in select (dropdown) list and cycle_id as value 
echo '<option value="'.$cycle_id.'">'.$cycle.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're going to have to use JavaScript if you don't want to reload the webpage. If you don't mind, then build a new URL with that variable as GET and build it showing the new drop-down box

Comment: when you post back the form, there will be a variable `$_POST["Week"]` available which contains the ID of the selected option in that dropdown. Or if you want to use the value client-side in Javascript before the page is refreshed then please clarify that, and you can google an example of it anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to make an ajax call on selection and pass the selected value to process your result in another file where you can run your query.

```
<select name="cycle_data" id="cycle_id">
   <option value="cycle1" > Cycle 1</option>
   <option value="cycle2" >Cycle 2</option>
</select>
```

Then lets do a script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#cycle_id").change(function(){ 
   var cycle_data = $(this).val(); 
   var dataString = "cycle_data="+cycle_data; 

    $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "get-data.php", 
    data: dataString, 
    success: function(result){ 
      // Process your result here
    }
    });
    });
   });
</script>
```